# Writing a letter of apology and requesting financial assistance

Tags: letter

Situation:
I have spent almost all of my money due to my wrong decisions, and I need to ask a person to help. He knows that is my fault, so it is very embarrassing to ask him for help, but due to private reasons, I have no choice. In the letter, I need to admit that I am wrong and show my regret , also I need to ask him for help.

I have found some related sample letter on google, but they are not suitable. They don’t include both “apology+requesting financial help” in the letter, so they are not useful. I think writing “I am writing for fiancial assistant... blah blah blah” in the first paragraph is quite impolite in my situation. However, I afraid that if I don’t state my purpose first, he will think that I am wasting his time.

Can anybody give me some suggestions of how to write this kind of letter? For example, how to express my regret and my request neatly in few sentences, so that I can use them in the first paragraph before going into details.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. This is a "what to write" question, which is off-topic for us because it is unique to you and unlikely to help others in the future.

Comment: @fairytale, this is likely to get closed for reasons stated by LaurenIpsum. However, in circumstances such as these, I would avoid form letters and samples and write from the heart. Even if the letter isn't as eloquent as a result, it will be more impactful. I would also concentrate part of the letter on how you intend to pay them back. When I have borrowed from family, I have worked out how much interest they will lose from their savings, how much interest I would have to pay on a loan, and met them in the middle with a clear repayment structure that I adhered to to the letter. Good luck.

Comment: There's a Stack called Interpersonal Questions (https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) that may have more people ready to answer this question.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+15%3A17-19&version=NIV

Comment: @Chris -- can you explain why the link is relevant?  Your comment isn't very "stand-alone." Thanks

Comment: @April.  It's an example of a brief, but effective piece of writing closely matching the situation of the OP.  The person referenced in the link took a large sum of money from a benefactor.  He completely wasted it ("wrong decisions").  He needs to simultaneously beg for forgiveness and ask for more funds.  He composes such a message (mentally, at least), delivers it, and is successful. ;)